# WCF: What exactly does IsInitiating do?

Tags: wcf

In some places I see that IsInitiating creates a new session. Other places say that it creates a new session only if needed. Which is correct?

Just to make it clear, I want to make sure I can call IService.Foo three times without three sessions being created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time an IsInitiating=true operation is called through a channel, the session begins. Future calls to IsInitiating=true operations do not start new sessions, they simply become part of the existing session. A session ends after an IsTerminating operation is called (this causes the client to close the channel). No further operations may be called through the channel once the IsTerminating operation returns. These properties give developers control over the order of operation invocation relative to the session lifetime.

[Sorry, Here is a link to the source.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.isinitiating.aspx)

Comment: does the WCF validates whether the `IsInitializing` was called before any other method? I tested here and I called other methods before the initializer method and WCF did not throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

Demarcation is to annotate service operations by some special attribute to determine the first and last operation in their execution order. Consider a service having 4 methods/operations named- SignIn(), GetDetails(). TransferFund() and SignOut(). In such a scenario, a user must be signed in and then try to fetch details and do transfer. If user signs out, then he should not be allowed for further requests until he signs in. To configure such type of execution order, Demarcation is required. There are two attributes:

```
IsInitiating (Default - True) 
IsTerminating (Default – False)
```

These attributes decide which operation should be called first and which should be last? For the above four operations, following can be one possible sequence:

```
[OperationContract(IsInitiating = True)]
 Bool SignIn()

[OperationContract(IsInitiating = false)]
 String GetDetails()

[OperationContract(IsInitiating = false)]
 Bool TransferFund()

[OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = True)]
 Bool SignOut()
```

Here initiation and termination refers to a session which is mandatory for demarcation, as service needs to know whether client has followed the particular sequence or not. Here operation 2,3 and 4 are set to `IsInitiating = false` so cannot be called first but can be called after an Isinitiating = True operation is called. Similarly, Operation 4 is annotated as `IsTerminating = True` that’s why when it is called, it terminates the session (along with underlying channel) and then client cannot make further calls until a fresh proxy is created and an `IsInitiating = True` operation is called. To use demarcation, the following configuration is necessary:

A session supportive binding
SessionMode set to Required
When IsTerminating operation is called, WCF discards the channel and never accepts further messages from it. If an operation is not decorated explicitly with any of these attributes, then default value of these attributes will be applicable to it.

That’s all for now.

At last, just recapitulate once - There are 3 things to remember for WCF session:

> 1. Sessionful binding
> 2. SessionMode service contract
> 3. InstanceContextMode service behavior

Demarcation defines first and last operation in execution order.