# Meaning of IsInitiating and IsOneWay in WCF OperationContract

Tags: wcf

i am very new in WCF. so often gaze for wcf code & article. after viewing many code i often stuck for very basic things and got no elaborate discussion for the below question. so here are my few basic question....and looking for details discussion with sample situation and with sample code.

```
[OperationContract(IsInitiating=false, IsOneWay=false)]
bool Add_Contact(int sessionkey, string Newusrname);
```

What is the meaning of IsInitiating=false or true. when i should set it true or false ? what is the meaning of IsOneWay=false or true. when i should set it true or false ?

i belief my question are very basic and lots of scholar every time monitoring this forum. i hope i will get the best answer in details with many situation like when one should choose which option over other option with few sample code for simulating situations. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679531/wcf-what-exactly-does-isinitiating-do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**IsInitiating**

The `IsInitiating` parameter specifies whether or not an operation implemented by the associated method
can initiate a session on the server. Session instancing is the ability to have separate instances of a class
be maintained for each client channel. This property controls whether an operation is allowed to be the
first operation called when a session is created. The default for this parameter is `true`, meaning that the
specified operation can be the first called on a channel. In this scenario, all following calls to this method
have no effect (meaning, no other sessions are created). If this parameter is set to `false`, the client is forced
to call other methods prior to calling this method.

This comes in handy when you are trying to set an “order of operation,” meaning that you need a specific
method to be called first because the other methods called depend on something returned from the
first method.

For example, the following contains three methods, or service operations. The first operation creates the
session and must be the first method called. The final operation, Logout, closes the session:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBuyStock
{
[OperationContract(IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]
void Login(user);
[OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
void BuyStock(string stocksymbol, int quantity);
[OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
void Logout(user);
}
```

Once the initiating method has been called, subsequent calls can be made to that method with no effect
to its initiating properties.

If any method other than the initiating method is called first, the following error is returned:

```
The operation ‘operationname’ cannot be the first operation to be called because
IsInitiating is false.
```

The initiating method must be called first, then other operations can be called.

**IsOneWay**

Service communication by default is bi-directional. Bi-directional service communication means that a
service operation can receive incoming messages and send a reply.

The IsOneWay parameter specifies whether a service operation returns a reply message. The default
value for this parameter is `false`, meaning that the method does not return a reply message.

The following example illustrates a one-way communication:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBuyStock
{
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void Login(user);
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
void BuyStock(string stocksymbol, int quantity);
}
```

In a one-way communication, the client initiates the communication and continues code execution and
does not wait for a response from the service. In a two-way communication, it waits for a response from
the service before continuing code execution.

The downside to using one-way communication is that the caller has no way of knowing whether or not
the service processed the message successfully.

Any methods that return a value where the `IsOneWay` property is set to `false` will return an exception.

**IsTerminating**

The `IsTerminating` property specifies whether a called service operation is to terminate the communication
session. The following example shows the last call,
`Logout()`, has the `IsTerminating` property set to `true`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBuyStock
{
[OperationContract(IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]
void Login(user);
[OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
void BuyStock(string stocksymbol, int quantity);
[OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
void Logout(user);
}
```

When the `IsTerminating` property is set to `true`, the session is closed after the reply message is sent (if
a reply message needs to be sent). On the client side, an `IsTerminating` value of `true` tells WCF to close
the channel only after the reply arrives at the client.

Comment: i do not understand this statement given by u....If this parameter is set to false, the client is forced to call other methods prior to calling this method.??

Comment: if i set IsOneWay=true then method will return something...am i right? here is one example [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
int BuyStock(string stocksymbol, int quantity);  is it right or wrong when IsOneWay = true ??

Comment: u did not discuss what is the meaning of IsTerminating option. if possible then please put some light on it. thanks

Comment: @Thomas, this answer above was pasted in from a book http://books.google.ie/books?id=EfJmiPx4PuEC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137#v=onepage&q&f=false. These attributes are to do with whether or not the service method will/can start or finish a session. It's related to long running converstations with the service api. Sometimes it's not possible to make a service method completely stateless.

Comment: @Thomas "If this parameter is set to false, the client is forced to call other methods prior to calling this method" means client cannot call a method which `IsInitiating` is set to `false` as the first method in a session, if he does then exception is thrown

Comment: @Thomas `[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)] int BuyStock(string stocksymbol, int quantity);` is wrong. If `IsOneWay` is set to `true`, that method's return type should be `void` since it should not return any value/reply to client else exception is thrown.

Comment: no i made mistake i think it should be [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)] int BuyStock(string stocksymbol) am i right now??

Comment: yup @Thomas, you are right now. But `IsOneWay` is `false` by default so no need to mention it explicitly.

Comment: This answer has at least 2 mistakes: `The default value for this parameter is false, meaning that the method does not return a reply message.` and `Any methods that return a value where the IsOneWay property is set to false will return an exception.`

Answer (score -2):

[OperationContract(IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]

> Blockquote

In above code IsInitiating property is set to true when we want to create session .

> Blockquote

We know login method is called first before other methods,hence we
use IsInitiating = true for login method and for other methods we set it as false.

> Blockquote

In the same way we use Isterminating=True for logout method then session is deleted.

Comment: What are the `Blockquote`s?